# How to track the number of click on mobile connect SMS link shortened by tiny or bitly?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there any way to track no. of clicks on bitly or tiny url used in SMS messages sent from SFMC.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a bit.ly shortened link, the number of click throughs is tracked automatically. Please see [Link Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_link_tracking.htm&type=5) in online help for further details.

Comment: For bitly urls, we have tracking information in the SMS itself. I want to track the tiny url. I guess tiny have their own tracking dashboard.